# Speech Recognition with learning capability

Tags: c#

how to create a speech recognition program in c# that learn and remember the last word that previously said.
should i use database to save every word i said.
The code below work fine but with limited grammar.
Sorry or my bad English.

Here the code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        add();
        remove();
    }
        [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern void LockWorkStation();
    private SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer;
    public SpeechSynthesizer reader;

    void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        recognize(e.Result);
    }
    void recognizer_SpeechRecognitionRejected(object sender, SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs e)
    {
        recognize(e.Result);
    }

    public void recognize(RecognitionResult e)
    {
        foreach(RecognizedPhrase r in e.Alternates)
        {

            if(r.Text=="system shutdown")
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Very Well";
                Process.Start("shutdown", "/s/t");
            }
            else if(r.Text=="system restart")
            {

                textBox1.Text = "See You In Short";
                Process.Start("restart", "/r/t 0");
            }
            else if (r.Text == "system open explorer")
            {

                textBox1.Text = "explorer open";
                Process.Start("explorer.exe");
            }
            else if (r.Text == "system open my document")
            {

                textBox1.Text = "document open";
                Process.Start("explorer.exe","/a");
            }
            else if (r.Text == "system open download")
            {

                textBox1.Text = "download open";
                Process.Start("C:/Users/Donz/Downloads");
            }
            else if (r.Text == "system open my personal drive")
            {

                textBox1.Text = "your personal drive is open";
                Process.Start("E:/");
            }
            else if (r.Text == "system what time now")
            {

                textBox1.Text ="time is" + DateTime.Now.ToString(" h mm ss tt");

            }
            else if (r.Text == "system date today")
            {

                textBox1.Text = "date is" + DateTime.Now.ToString(" dd mm yyyy");

            }
            //else if (r.Text == "system lock")
            //{
            //    textBox1.Text = "Go find some one to do a work for you";
            //    //LockWorkStation();
            //}
            else if (r.Text == "system what is your name")
            {
                textBox1.Text = "i don't have a name, am just a piece of code compress of if and else";

            }
            else if (r.Text == "system what is this")
            {
                textBox1.Text = "let me see it";


            }
            else if (r.Text == "system very good")
            {
                textBox1.Text = "thank you";


            }
            else if (r.Text == "system good bye see you next time")
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Good bye i will see you soon";


            }
            else if (r.Text == "system close")
            {
                pictureBox1.Visible = true;
                textBox1.Text = "System will close in.";
                timer1.Start();

            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = "i don't get you i will try to learn";
            }

        }
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;

        GrammarBuilder grammerbuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
        grammerbuilder.Append(new Choices("system"));

        grammerbuilder.Append(new Choices("shutdown", "restart", "lock", "close", "what is your name", "what is this","very good","good bye see you next time","open explorer","open my document","open download","open my computer","open my personal drive","what time now","date today"));
        recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        recognizer.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
        recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(grammerbuilder));
        //recognizer.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
        recognizer.SpeechRecognized += recognizer_SpeechRecognized;
        recognizer.SpeechRecognitionRejected += recognizer_SpeechRecognitionRejected;
        recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        textBox1.Text = "Greting, How may i help you";


    }


    void reader_sp(object sender, SpeakCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "IDLE";
    }

    private void text_check(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        reader.Dispose();
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();

            reader.SpeakAsync(textBox1.Text);
            label1.Text = "Speaking";

            reader.SpeakCompleted += new EventHandler<SpeakCompletedEventArgs>(reader_sp);

        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value + 1;


        if (progressBar1.Value == 40)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "4";
        }
        if (progressBar1.Value == 60)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "3";
        }
        if (progressBar1.Value == 80)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "2";
        }
        if (progressBar1.Value == 90)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "1";
        }
        if (progressBar1.Value == 98)
        {

            textBox1.Text = "1";
            timer1.Stop();
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }



    System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
    static ManagementEventWatcher w = null;
    public void remove()
    {
        WqlEventQuery q;
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2");
        scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;

        try
        {

            q = new WqlEventQuery();
            q.EventClassName = "__InstanceDeletionEvent";
            q.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
            q.Condition = "TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBControllerdevice'";
            w = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, q);
            w.EventArrived += USBRemoved;

            w.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {


            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            if (w != null)
            {
                w.Stop();

            }
        }


    }
    public void add()
    {
        WqlEventQuery q;
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2");
        scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;

        try
        {

            q = new WqlEventQuery();
            q.EventClassName = "__InstanceCreationEvent";
            q.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
            q.Condition = "TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBControllerdevice'";
            w = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, q);
            w.EventArrived += USBInsert;

            w.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            if (w != null)
            {
                w.Stop();

            }
        }
    }

    public void USBInsert(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        player.SoundLocation = "C:/Users/Donz/Desktop/Today/Voice Recognition/lockPc/lockPc/Resources/tone/insert.wav";

        player.Play();
    }



    public void USBRemoved(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        player.SoundLocation = "C:/Users/Donz/Desktop/Today/Voice Recognition/lockPc/lockPc/Resources/tone/remove.wav";
        player.Play();
    }

}
```

Sample Code would be grateful
Donz
India, Meghalaya

Comment: what do you mean by "learn" and "remember" ?  if you only need to return the last word you said, can't you just use a variable?  if the "memory" needs to persist across instances of when the code is run, then yes, you should store the last word in a database.

Comment: Yes ofcouse virtually, but that can be done only by grammar, what i mean is, when i speak suppose i say "my name is donz", so it will remember that word "donz" when i run again. I know the code is not yet full. i try to switch to DictationGrammar(); but it didnot recognize. like this:
recognizer.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use switch-case statement.
Ex.:

```
    switch (example)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("Something");
                break;
        }
```